# Classic asp include virtual with backslash doesn't work on IIS7.5 (works with slash)

Tags: asp-classic, include, iis-7.5

We have this classic asp application that I tried to install on IIS7.5 (Windows 2008 Server R2). Everything works except that include virtual statements with backslash, e.g.
**<!-- #include virtual="\includes\file.inc"-->**
doesn't work even though I enabled "Enable parent paths" in IIS.

It **does** work if I change the backslash () to slash (/), i.e.
**<!-- #include virtual="/includes/file.inc"-->**

This code has been working for a long time and I'm not keen on changing that kind of code at this point. Is there some setting that I can set get this to work so I can use the code as it is?

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with parent paths.  If `\` used work then it was a quirk because the virtual path is expected to follow the conventions of a URL.

You will need to hunt down all uses of the virtual attribute and change to the correct use of `/`